# Can't present imagepicker immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a Tab bar controller, when I tap the third tab bar button I present a `UIViewcontroller`. In the `viewWillAppear` of this vc I'm presenting a `UIImagepickerController` that works fine. The problem is I can't display it on the screen immediately when I open the view. First the vc shows up and after 0.4-0.5 sec the image picker. So I would like to present the image picker first and present the vc after the user took an image. I tried to call the picker from `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` too, but nothing changed.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (imagePickerWasPresented == NO)
    {
        imagePickerWasPresented = YES;

        self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;


        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];

        [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Am I calling it in a wrong place?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - instead of calling the VC and then the UIImagePicker, call the UIImagePicker directly.

When you are done taking a picture/video:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {}
```

you will go to this standard delegate method, call the VC from here. This way you will immediately go to the ImagePicker and only have a transition would you choose to do something with the taken content afterwards which is less frustrating/ugly.

Answer (score 1):

No, your calling it in an okay place, that's just how iOS does it; if you present multiple modals on top of each other, one gets presented after the other, including the animation. A solution that would work for your problem is to present a UINavigationController instead of your UIViewController. Set the navigation controller up to have ViewController as the root viewcontroller, but also push your imagepickercontroller onto the stack. Present this navigationcontroller and it should go right to your imagepickercontroller. Otherwise, try presenting both uiviewcontroller and imagepickercontroller with animation set to NO and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

try this to see how close that gets you then adapt to your needs.  when i gave it a quick test it seemed to do what you were asking.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;

    UIViewController * vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];


    UITabBarController * tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController, nil];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

    tabBarController.delegate = self;

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                          nil];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [vc presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];

    return YES;

}
```

Comment: i should add this also illustrates pretty clearly what Alex mentioned in respect to pushing a view controller onto a nav controller that is added to a tabbar controller.

Comment: I have 3 more different method that interacts with the image picker in the vc so I would rather neglect the AppDelegate.

Comment: set the delegate to the vc then

Answer (score 1):

### UIImage as a PopOver

Gallery mode:

```
BOOL hasGallery = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = hasGalleryt ? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary :    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
if (self.popoverController != nil)
{
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.popoverController=nil;
}
self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[self.imageView frame]
                                   fromView:[self.imageView superview]];
popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 300) ;
popoverRect.origin.x = popoverRect.origin.x;
[self.popoverController
 presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect
 inView:self.view
 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
 animated:YES];
```

Camera mode:

```
BOOL hasCamera = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = hasCamera ? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera :    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
if (self.popoverController != nil)
{
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.popoverController = nil;
}
self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[self.imageView frame]
                                   fromView:[self.imageView superview]];
popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 300) ;
popoverRect.origin.x = popoverRect.origin.x;
[self.popoverController
 presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect
 inView:self.view
 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
 animated:YES];
```

Remember to give to the .h File `@interface` the delegates, like this:

```
@interface the UIViewController: UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: Could you link a sample? I've never made it as a PopOver.